# May I know why the parameter to this function isn't of int type? I don't understand the whole concept of the pointer here

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

I am learning data structures and algorithms and came across Linked list, which uses pointers. However, I don't understand how they are being used in the codes below. Can anyone guide me on this?

```
int Linkedlist :: addatEnd(node* n){
    if(head == NULL){
        head = n;
        n->next = NULL;
    }else{
        node* n2 = getlastnode();
        n2->next = n;
    }
}
```

Shouldn't the parameter to the function addatEnd() be of int type? But if it really is a pointer, does it mean it will have to point to a certain memory address?

Comment: It's naughty code since it has a type `int` but no explicit return value. Best study a decent linked list implementation.

Comment: @YSC alright, I added it as an answer.

Comment: Looks like a badly designed list interface. I would recommend researching somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Shouldn't the parameter to the function addatEnd() be of int type?

No.

A linked list consists of nodes. Each node will indirectly link (i.e. refer, i.e. point) to the next node, until the last node which terminates the list. An integer cannot indirectly point to the next node, so nodes of a linked list cannot be an integers.

> But if it really is a pointer, does it mean it will have to point to a certain memory address?

Yes. It will have to point to some `node` instance (because the function indirects through the pointer). That instance will be stored in some memory address.

---

P.S. The function is broken.

It sets `n->next` to null only if it is the only element of the list. It fails to set `n->next` when there are other nodes.

Furthermore, it is declared to return `int` but fails to do so. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

Comment: Is it correct to say that a node is itself a pointer ? which contains a next pointer that points to another node?

Comment: @Ray It would not be correct, or at least it would be highly unconventional. `node` is a class type. Technically, it is a wrapper for a pointer (or pointers in case of doubly linked list) just like a smart pointer is, but it also carries the data associated with the list element, so being a wrapper around pointer(s) is not its only purpose.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't the parameter to the function addatEnd() be of int type?

It could be implemented in a different way, but as it currently is, it makes sense for it to take a `node*` instead.

> But if it really is a pointer, does it mean it will have to point to a
>   certain memory address?

Generally, pointers that are passed as a parameter don't have to point to a valid memory address. They can also be null pointers, and the function could detect that and proceed accordingly.

In this case, a valid pointer has to be passed, however, because the function is trying to modify the object, at least if `head == NULL`:

```
n->next = NULL;
```

If `n` doesn't point to a valid `node`, this is undefined behavior and will likely crash the program, or do even worse.

Comment: @YSC thank you for your corrections, I changed that passage. With the "always representing a number" bit I meant that the underlying memory is always going to have a bit pattern which can be interpreted as a number. I can't seem to word it in a way that makes much sense in the context of this question and it's going off a tangent anyway, so I removed it.

Comment: About _"underlying memory is always going to have a bit pattern which can be interpreted as a number"_ FYI you cannot. This is specifically disallowed to read/interpret uninitialized memory in C++.

Answer (score 0):

`node` is a separate data structure. And the `node* n` means, whoever is calling `addatEnd(node* n)` is passing the node's address as an argument. Callee(the one calling your function) is doing :

```
Node n;//Instaniating node data structure
addatEnd(&node);//Passing the address of the node data structure to your function
```

The address of node is passed so that it does not make a separate copy the node structure and do operations on it, and whatever operations we do on the copy of the node will not be reflected on the original node.

We want to do operations on the original node data structure, hence passing the address of node so we can do operations on the memory location where the node was originally instantiated.